# How to sort output by the sum of 4 columns? SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have 4 columns each containing a number. I need the `echo` to output in such an order, that the row with the biggest sum of numbers (from each of the 4 columns) is the first.

For example:

```
1)id1|1 |10|1 |2|
2)id2|3 |12|43|1|
3)id3|12|0 |1 |1|
```

After ordering:

```
1)id2|3 |12|43|1
2)id1|1 |10|1 |2
3)id3|12|0 |1 |1
```

One option is to make a "sum" column... but that would require updating it each time one of the numbers in one of the columns changes... Is there a more simple solution?
For example, I output the sum of numbers of each `id` when it is displayed in a single `<div>`, I add them with a function before outputing the `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY (column1+column2+column3+column4) DESC
```

will get it done

Comment: Would `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY (column1+column2+column3+column4) DESC` be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this mysql statement:

```
SELECT (row1 + row2 + row3 + row4) sum FROM your_table
```